# Building a mulit-dynamic HTML-Table with Wicket

Tags: wicket, html-table

I have a very strange dynamic table that represents a daily shopping cart. The table lists a variable amount of options for each day. Each day can have 0 or even n options. The user, can add any of this n options to his selections. So the options part and also  the selections part can grow dynamically.

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---
|  THE  | OPTIONS                       | SELECTIONS                  ...
|  DAY  +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---
|       | OPT 1 | OPT 2 | OPT3  | OPT n | 1.SEL | 2.SEL | 3.SEL |     ...
+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+===
| day 1 | opt 1 | opt 2 |       |       | opt 2 | opt 1 | opt 1 |     ...
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---
| day 2 | opt 1 | opt 2 | opt 3 | opt n | opt n |       |       |     ...
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---
| day 3 | opt 1 | opt 2 |       |       | opt 1 |       |       |     ...
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---
| day 4 |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |     ...
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---
| day 5 | opt 1 | opt 2 |       |       | opt 2 |       |       |     ...
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---
| day 6 | opt 1 |             ...
+-------+-------+---
| day 7 |               ...
+-------+---
|                 ...
+---
```

Now I want to write code, that can generate a dynamic table, that considers the variable amount of days, options and selections. The tricky part is to dynamically add empty cells to the options columns as well as to the selection columns so that all cells have the right alignment to their corresponding table part.

I always found some examples, but all suffer from calculation the right amount of option-cells to align the user selections.

Do you have any suggestions how to build such a table? Or do you have any further considerations?

Answer (score 0):

First you should calculate the maximum number of existing options and selections, let them be N and M.

Then after rendering the options of a day, determine the number of blank cells (N - current number of options) And add the same number of empty `<td>` of alternatively only one `<td>` with the attribute `hspan` set to the number of blank cells.

And do the same for selections.